# How to automatically update the database on application start up?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

A run time error occurs when i run my code asking me to do a code migration to update my database. I am not sure how to do this, can anyone help me?

> The model backing the 'ApplicationDbContext' context has changed since
>   the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to
>   update the database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you must enable automatic migrations in your context configuration file

```
internal class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<YourContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        this.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        this.AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = false;
    }
```

Comment: Is this done in the Startup.cs class cause configurations calss does not exist. Or what do you mean by context configuration file.

Comment: read this http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application